# how to install and use Winforms in VSCode on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, visual-studio-code, windows-forms-designer

(.NET Core Version 3.0.103 (Commit: b7ef045669), Platform/OS: ubuntu linux 18.04-x64, Winforms branch version (date): Thu Mar 26 07:37:13 2020 -0700, VSCode 1.43.2)

I cloned current version of Winforms from Github, tried to use appropriate installation script (build.sh) but finally got only error message ([I think it's a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3018)).
Possibly someone was more succefull?
(Even though Winforms Designer doesn't still work in VSCode on Linux as I got from documentation there should be possibility to create Windows Form Application templates from console, port existing application from .NET Framework to .NET Core and so on).
So can anyone share your experience about this?

Answer (score 2):

Winforms is currently a [Windows-only technology](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-for-windows-desktop/) in the .NET Core runtime. I haven't seen an instance of someone circumvening this limitation.

> .NET Core (and in the future .NET 5 that is built on top of .NET Core) will be the future of .NET. We are committed to support .NET Framework for years to come, however it will not be receiving any new features, those will only be added to .NET Core (and eventually .NET 5). To improve Windows desktop stacks and enable .NET desktop developers to benefit from all the updates of the future, we brought Windows Forms and WPF to .NET Core. **They will still remain Windows-only technologies because there are tightly coupled dependencies to Windows APIs**. But .NET Core, besides being cross-platform, has many other features that can enhance desktop applications.

The [Mono Project](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) supports Winforms, which can be run on linux, however I'm unaware of how to develop Winforms via Mono on vscode.

Comment: thanks!
but, I tried to install Mono WinForms Designer (according to this - https://www.mono-project.com/archived/winforms_designer/), and got only some errors during installation, and according to date of project files in Github this project is dead now.
anyway, I installed curren version of MonoDevelop, it looks very pretty- but I couldn't find how to create there even simple windows forms application's project (similar as in Visual Studio).
Maybe you can help with some links for helpful articles/documentation for this case?

Comment: Future readers should try to move away from Mono, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ There isn't enough goodies there for you any more.